# javascript background horizontal/vertical scroll to element site:beyond 911

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone break down **CONCEPTUALLY** how this was achieved?

http://content.time.com/time/beyond911/

I know it loads "grid.html" which is tiled and depending how you click, becomes "infinite" (try clicking a corner image over and over again). Just not sure how it centers on the element that is clicked, or the use of arrows to select adjacent elements.

thanks

Comment: Too bad they didn't make it work on Firefox. Fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using the `-webkit-transform: translate(top, left);` on the table to effect the centering. It shifts the table up and down and left and right. For the "infinte" scroll, they are literally moving the table rows and columns around in the DOM. Also, lots of math related to the size of the rows and columns.